# Using kubectl to tear down from yaml

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubectl

I created a .yaml file following [this tutorial](https://www.oreilly.com/ideas/how-to-manage-docker-containers-in-kubernetes-with-java).  You deploy the web service with `kubectl apply -f shopfront-service.yaml`.  So far so good.  The author says nothing though about how to tear everything down.

With TerraForm or CloudFormation you use the same .yaml file to remove all resources.  I would think that K8 would also support cleaning up using the same .yaml file, but I can't find any way to do this.

Is there a way to delete resources with the same .yaml file used to create the deployment?

Answer (score 1):

`kubectl delete -f shopfront-service.yaml`
see [kubectl delete docs](https://kubernetes-v1-4.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_delete/)